# Get related record one to many relationships Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to check if the current user has already a record for the current date.The User entity has many Timerecord and Timerecord has one User. So far, 
This two entities resides in two different bundles

```
   Project
       UserBundle
       TimerecordBundle
```

controller

```
$user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
        $userr = $user->getUsername();
        $alreadyLoggedIn = $em->getRepository('EmployeeBundle:Timerecord')->findAlreadyTimedInToday($userr);
        var_dump($alreadyLoggedIn);
        die();
```

Respository

```
  public function findAlreadyTimedInToday($userr)
{

    return $this
         ->createQueryBuilder('t')
         ->select('u.username')
         ->from('User u')
         ->join('u.Timerecord t')
         ->where('u.username LIKE :currentuser')
         ->setParameter('currentuser',$userr)
         ->getQuery()
         ->getSingleResult()
    ;     
}
```

I got this exception

> Warning: Missing argument 2 for Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder::from()

How do you fetch the related user in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The alias for the `from` part should be given to the second argument.

Change your method to this:

```
public function findAlreadyTimedInToday($userr)
{
    return $this
         ->createQueryBuilder('t')
         ->select('u.username')
         ->from('User', 'u')
         ->join('u.Timerecord', 't')
         ->where('u.username LIKE :currentuser')
         ->setParameter('currentuser', $userr)
         ->getQuery()
         ->getSingleResult()
    ;     
}
```

Comment: oh I forgot, user and timerecord are in different bundles, somthing like userbundle and timerecordbundle..Is it it relevant to to query like this?  ->from('Project\UserBundl:User', 'u')